# javascript regex lookahead why abc match?

Tags: javascript, regex

Input text is:

```
test 
abc abc
```

I want to get all text before abc with

```
.+(?=abc)
```

https://regex101.com/r/4XiJ2r/1

why with 2 `abc` it matches the first one?

Comment: Because you only told it to match `.+` in front of `abc`, so in `abc abc` that's only the first four characters? `cake abc` will match `cake `, and `abc cake` will match nothing.

Comment: If you want to get all text before `abc`, then just `(.*)abc`

Comment: The positive lookahead (`(?=)`) asserts that what is within the group comes after the match while excluding what's actually in the lookahead from the match. It matches the first one because the second one doesn't have `abc` after it.

Comment: If you want to include `test\n` in the match, add the `s` flag. If you want every match before `abc`, add the `?` qualifier. If you want to include empty results, change the `+` quantifier to `*`. So: `/.*?(?=abc)/gs`. It’s unclear what else you expect to happen.

Comment: @tarkh it matches all abc : I want the reverse

Comment: @SebastianSimon it's weird it matches bc : I don't want bc

Comment: @user310291 Please [edit] your post and specify what exactly you want to match. Your comments don’t make it any clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle new lines and you don't need global search, because capturing must stop only before first `abc` appearance, so remove `m` and `g` flag and add singleline flag `s`:

```js
const str = `test
abc abc`;

const result = str.match(/.*?(?=abc)/s);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `/.*?(?=abc)/ms` would be much simpler.

Comment: The `m` flag makes the caret `^` match *start of line* and `$` *end of line*. None of these are used in your pattern if I see right. :) I'd rather drop the `m` and add a `^` start anchor for *string start*. Or as @SebastianSimon mentions, to use `.*?` together with the `s` *singleline* flag as far as supported.

Comment: @bobblebubble, thanks for comments, you both (SebastianSimon) right, edited my answer based on your corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a ? (to make it `.+?(?=abc)`) to your quantifier will make it lazy, so it'll stop at the first ocurrence, but it will still find the other ocurrences and put them in different "groups":
https://regex101.com/r/BjrowX/1

Comment: I don't want to match abc at all.

Comment: If you don't want to match `abc`, use a negative lookahead to restrict it.

Comment: Have you checked the link I provided? The first group returns everything before the first abc and it does not include abc in it. If that's not what you want, can you elaborate on your specific necessity.

Comment: @GuilhermeLofranoCorneto yes but sorry it's my mistake my input example was truncated by error.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` quantifier requires the match to be at least 1 character. In `abc abc` there's nothing before the first `abc`, so it can't be the match. So the match is everything before the second `abc`.

Comment: made a mistake for input : added test. So I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: `test` is irrelevant since `.` doesn't match newlines by default.